# Play next video within post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5-video, playlist

So I have a custom post type in WordPress that displays html5 videos. Is there a way I could automatically play the next video once it's over and still remain on the same post? I'm thinking something like [this](https://www.cnn.com/videos/business/2021/01/28/virgin-hyperloop-concept-video-orig.cnn-business/video/playlists/business-news/) would be the perfect example.

Here's a [link](https://earthxdev.wpengine.com/nowthisearth-post/everything-you-need-to-know-about-greenwashing/) to what I have so far.

I have a custom post type called `nowthisearth_post` and a custom field `nowthisearth_media_url` that is pulling in the link to the MP4 file. Right now there are 6 posts and would like for it to proceed to the next one after the video ends. Here's what I have right now..

I started off using the `get_next_post();` function but it doesn't seem to work. I'm thinking maybe it would need to be converted into some sort of video playlist with thumbnails at the bottom.

```
<div class="container-fluid nowthis-header">
<div class="container" style="z-index:11;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <?php $mrssfeed_url = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'nowthisearth_media_url', true);?>
            <video class="nowthis-video" style="" width="1280" height="720" autoplay="true" controls loop>
              <source src="<?php echo $mrssfeed_url ?>" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <?php $next_post = get_next_post();
            if ( is_a( $next_post , 'nowthisearth_post' ) ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $next_post->ID ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the ended event?

Comment: Yes, once the video ends, I would like for it to play the next video but still remain on the same post page. Similar to how CNN does it.

Comment: So, does adding an event listener for the ended event help?